# Loop all database records and change the current values of a column, no data truncate or loss

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, truncate

I want to alter an SQL Server database column, it is currently `Pssn Char(9)`, I want it to be `Pssn Char(4)` knowing that the database contains data currently in this column, and I want all values in this column to be the 4 characters to the right.

```
Pssn = Right(Pssn, 4)
```

I need a way to loop all database records and change the current values of `Pssn` column, to insure no data is lost, and then to modify the column type to `Char(4)` instead of `Char(9)`.

Comment: which database are you using ? MYSQL/SQLSERVER ?

Comment: You say modify column type, do you mean table column type, or result set column? Table column type is changed used ALTER TABLE, result set column is changed using CAST. You modify data using the SQL statement UPDATE.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? What is it? Those are two very different beasts

Comment: Please Sir, notice the solution in just came up with

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use a loop** or any other RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) approach! You can do this much more easily in **only single, nice, **set-based** SQL statement.

To update the `PSSN` column to the 4 right most characters, use this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Pssn = RIGHT(Pssn, 4)
```

**OF COURSE:** if you have values that are **longer** than 4 characters, ***those will be truncated!*** Be careful - and be sure to have a **backup** of your data before you start this!

Then, once that's done, you can easily update the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN Pssn CHAR(4) NULL    -- or NOT NULL - depending on what you need
```

Comment: the idea is that i don't want the existing data to be truncated, and in the way you are suggesting sir, i will need to create another loop on the backup database to fill the correct values.

Comment: @NadaNaeem: well, what do you want to do if a column's value is more than 4 characters long??

Comment: the values are all more than 4 characters long, 9 chars long. 
I want the value of 9 chars to be replaced with the Right 4 chars of that value it self. 

I have solved this issue, and my data base now is exactly as i wanted.

Comment: sir is there any other best practice solution? @marc-s

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this :

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Pssn = RIGHT(Pssn, 4)
```